# Google App Engine / Drive SDK: catching a lot HTTP Deadline exceptions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

Our app is deployed on the Google App Engine, Python runtime (2.7) and is consuming the Drive API. More and more it catches `HTTPException` because of an exceeded deadline, on different endpoints (Drive, OAuth, etc.)

We have implemented an exponential back-off mechanism with 5 tries. Our app is more and more reaching this limit (this morning for example we had a lot of these exceptions).

What could be the origin of this issues? Is it possible to increase the timeout delay?

Thanks for your help.

Here's a full stacktrace (OAuth2 API):

```
2013-06-07 21:11:10,851 ERROR An error occurred : Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unishared-gae/production.367909734400765242/main.py", line 733, in get
    creds = self.GetCodeCredentials() or self.GetSessionCredentials()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unishared-gae/production.367909734400765242/main.py", line 301, in GetCodeCredentials
    creds = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
  File "lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 1283, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 500, in getresponse
    raise HTTPException(str(e))
```

Comment: What's your URLFetch deadline limit? It should by default 60 secs for request handlers and it's well below our average API latency. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: I tried that, at the beginning of my main.py: 
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(45) httplib2.Http(timeout=45) but does not change the things

Comment: Same problem here, also mentioned in [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/BCdXSpDDYWc). On my side it happens ~5s after opening a URL, way before hitting the 60s.

Comment: Had confirmation [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024282/how-to-avoid-failed-to-retrieve-access-token-error-invalid-grant-in/17027974?noredirect=1#comment24649419_17027974) from a Google engineer that there's not much we can do as it's purely Google-side, and that they're working on it.

Comment: Good to know! This morning Google OAuth2 seems completely down. Many services, including ours are not accessible through Google sign-in/up. Any informations about that?

Comment: Any progress on that? Despite I'm using exponential backoff to catch/retry on these, I still get a LOT per day..

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://blog.bossylobster.com/2011/11/python-metaclass-for-extra-bad-errors.html) blog post published in 2011 talks about how to catch DeadlineExceededError with metaclass instead of using decorators. I do not sure this guides or solves you, but gives you a idea that may be helpful.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext.deferred import defer
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import RequestHandler
from google.appengine.runtime import DeadlineExceededError
import sys
from traceback import format_exception
from SOME_APP_SPECIFIC_LIBRARY import serve_500
from LAST_POST import email_admins

class DecorateHttpVerbsMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, cls_attr):
        verbs = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        for verb in verbs:
            if verb in cls_attr and isinstance(cls_attr[verb], function):
                cls_attr[verb] = deadline_decorator(cls_attr[verb])

        return super(DecorateHttpVerbsMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name,
                                                              bases, cls_attr)

class ExtendedHandler(RequestHandler):
    __metaclass__ = DecorateHttpVerbsMetaclass

    def handle_exception(self, exception, debug_mode):
        traceback_info = ''.join(format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
        email_admins(traceback_info, defer_now=True)

        serve_500(self)
```